# Слишком медленный SQL-запрос с использованием UNION

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос очистки мусора из базы, который выглядит как

```
DELETE LOW_PRIORITY dt FROM dates AS dt WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM table1 AS t1 WHERE t1.field1 = dt._id
  UNION SELECT 1 FROM table2 AS t2 WHERE t2.field2 = dt._id
  UNION ... и т.д.
)
```

Проблема в том, что команда UNION выполняется *ну очень* медленно ввиду того, что записей в таблицах много.
Выходит, нужно всё это заменить чем-то нормальным по скорости, но придумать ничего путного так и не смог…

Прошу «помощь зала» :)

Comment: Во первых стоит делать `UNION ALL`, он немного быстрее. Во вторых основная проблема скорее в not exists, если записей много. сделайте `dt NOT IN (select dt from tab1 union all select dt from tab2 ...)`

Comment: И в третьих, любые попытки оптимизации, так же как и вопросы об оптимизации без приведенного плана выполнения бесполезны

Comment: `NOT IN` использовать нельзя. Т.к. в этом случае СУБД создаёт временную таблицу и пытается сохранить в неё все варианты значений. А это — миллионы(!) записей. Что напрочь завесит систему.
Или я не прав?

Comment: ну это зависит от природы данных. в вопросе об этом ни слова нет. поэтому я и сказал, что заниматься оптимизацией не видя плана выполнения невозможно. А варианты разные бывают, в одних not exists быстрее, в других not in, пробовать надо. Сильно зависит от того, сколько записей в первой таблице и сколько во внутренних. Сто тысяч раз выполнять union, ради каждой отдельной записи в первой таблице то же очень плохо. А если в тех таблицах не дай дог нет индекса по полю даты... Тем более, что union без all это так же гарантированное создание временной таблицы и группировка.

Comment: @Mike, Извините, я не понимаю, что такое «план выполнения».
Суть: В первой таблице хранятся все записи о датах. Для начала их будет примерно 3 миллиона.
Все прочие таблицы ссылаются на эти данные по id. Записей в прочих таблицах (для начала) от нескольких десятков тысяч до полутора миллионов в каждой.

Указанный выше запрос очистки мусора выполняется в конце основной работы случайно с малой вероятностью (примерно 1/10000).

Comment: план выполнения это то что дает команда explain. google: "mysql план выполнения"

Comment: ну с not exists вы получаете выполнение блока с union 3 миллиона раз. А как эти даты в первой таблице вообще появляются и зачем она  нужна, там кроме поля id много еще других полей ?

Comment: Да, там блок полей. Ибо «дата» там немного хитрая — она может быть (в зависимости от ситуации) одновременно и приблизительной, и промежутком, и последовательностью дат… PS. Про план выполнения понял. Буду разбираться. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть только три варианта удаления. Первый - приведен Вами. Второй:

```
DELETE LOW_PRIORITY dt FROM dates AS dt WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT t1.field1 FROM table1 AS t1
    UNION ALL
  SELECT t2.filed2 FROM table2 AS t2
)
```

Третий:

```
DELETE LOW_PRIORITY dt FROM dates AS dt
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t1.field1 as id FROM table1 AS t1
      UNION ALL
    SELECT t2.filed2 FROM table2 AS t2
  ) X
    ON dt.id=X.id
  WHERE X.id IS NULL
```

Так же возможны вариации на тему вынесения выборок из таблиц tableN из union  отдельно, вроде нескольких LEFT JOIN и проверки в конце нескольких условий на NULL. Или нескольких NOT IN/NOT EXISTS.

Очень помогли бы индексы на поля fileldN, наверняка они нужны не только этому запросу. Предлагаю попробовать все эти варианты, посмотреть планы выполнения по EXLAIN и решить какой лучше будет работать на ваших данных.